# Why does MTKView persist without being referenced? How do I clean it up?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, metal

I noticed that when I remove all references to an instance of my MTKView subclass, or never create any in the first place, the instance still persists long after and continues drawing. This can be demonstrated by calling the `makeLeak` method below.

**Source:**

```
class MTKViewSubclass: MTKView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        print("MTKViewSubclass draw")
    }
}

func makeLeak() {
    // Make an MTKViewSubclass without storing a reference to it.
    let _ = MTKViewSubclass(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100), device: nil)
}
```

**Output:**

```
MTKViewSubclass draw
MTKViewSubclass draw
MTKViewSubclass draw
...
```

Given that the draw method continues to be called, it makes sense that the MTKView's display link is keeping it alive. Xcode's Memory Graph Hierarchy in the Debug navigator seems to confirm that, though I'm not an expert at reading it.

It surprises me that the MTKView draws even when it is not in the view hierarchy. In any case, how can I make sure it's cleaned up? I have a view controller with an MTKView that may be instantiated and freed many times.

**Edit:** Interestingly, while pausing the MTKView with `isPaused` seems to remove its display link reference, the view still persists. The Memory Graph Hierarchy shows a reference from the MTKView's CAMetalLayer to the view itself, among other references. I don't know which references are strong.

Comment: Which version of iOS are you seeing this on? Does anything change if you set the view's `isPaused` property to `true`?

Comment: I'm running iOS 9.3.5 on an iPod Touch. I've added the `isPaused` case to the question. Thanks.

Comment: This is a [known bug](http://openradar.appspot.com/23977735) in iOS 9.

Comment: Perfect! The workaround shown there solves my problem. And next time I think I've found a bug I'll know where to check. Thanks @warrenm